# How to position the image right under the last paragraph in vba?

Tags: vba

I used VBA to create a word document and I added picture in it. 
However, I would like to locate the picture exactly under the last paragraph instead of a fixed position.
 
The anchor seems malfunctioning right after I added the PageSetup parts in the code. Did I do something wrong?
Is it possible to position the picture right under the last paragraph if I cannot use anchor?

```
Public Sub create()

Dim certpara As Word.Paragraph
Dim certdoc As Word.Document
Dim certapp As Word.Application

Set certapp = New Word.Application

certapp.Visible = True

Set certdoc = certapp.Documents.Add

certdoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = certapp.InchesToPoints(0.59)
certdoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = certapp.InchesToPoints(0.39)
certdoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = certapp.InchesToPoints(0.79)
certdoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = certapp.InchesToPoints(0.79)

Dim i As Integer
Dim v As Integer

v = Range("A1").Value

For i = 1 To v
    certdoc.Paragraphs.Add
    Set certpara = certdoc.Paragraphs.Last
    certpara.Range.Text = "aaa"
Next i

Dim location As String
location = "D:\C3000.jpg"

certdoc.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=location, _
LinkToFile:=False, _
SaveWithDocument:=True, _
Left:=300, _
Top:=230, _
Anchor:=certpara.Range, _
width:=130, _
Height:=91

certdoc.Shapes(1).WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always bookmark the position directly after the last paragraph is inserted and insert at that position (instead of the anchor), or insert at a redefined range.  Since the second is less involved:

*After you define your image location:*

```
certpara.Collapse wdCollapseStart
'I had some trouble understanding your question so use the next line at your discretion
certpara.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1 
certpara.Select

ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=location, _
LinkToFile:=False, _
SaveWithDocument:=True, _
Anchor:=Selection.Range
```